# Xcode static library error: unknown option character `f' in: -fobjc-link-runtime

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, linker

I try to build a static library which "Implicitly link Objective-C Runtime Support", but build fail at link step with the next message:
`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: unknown option character 'f' in: -fobjc-link-runtime`

I have no idea why this happens, so if you know please help me.

Answer (score 1):

The `libtool` command doesn't take a `-fobjc-link-runtime` argument to it.   It sounds like this erroneously snuck into your Xcode project.   I would suggest the following:

1. Open Xcode
2. Select your project and the Build Settings tab
3. In the Search box type in `-fobjc-link-runtime` and there should be at least one line in the Build Settings that corresponds
4. It the item isn't on a compiler-related line, try removing it and re-building

If you don't find it, then it sounds like the `libtool` arguments are somehow unexpectedly including the arguments from the compiler.

If this is the case, which version of Xcode, and which compiler are you using?

Comment: In my project `libtool` option `-fobjc-link-runtime` is linked with `Implicitly link Objective-C Runtime Support` option from `Apple LLVM compiler 4.2 - Language`. The wired thick is that this happens only for one project.

Comment: When I search for `-fobjc-link-runtime` in Build Settings tab I don't find anything. I don't found any method to view the options of compile and link commands before build (not in the log) in order to remove the option from the link command. My Xcode version is 4.6.2.

Comment: Have you tried changing that individual project to use LLVM Clang instead of LLVM 4.2?   Or does it require 4.2 explicitly?

Comment: When you say without success, did it fail to compile with LLVM, or did the libtool failure recur?   If the latter, you may need to pop open the XML file with a text editor and do a quick search for `-fobjc-link-runtime` and consider removing it.   Obviously backup before doing this.